# android app crashes when redirecting to new activity

Tags: java, android

I am totally new with android, i created an app with basic activity and then added a button to direct to another activity, it worked but whenever i click the button to go to the new activity page the app get crashed

am getting the following error:

```
10/02 15:22:04: Launching app
$ adb push C:\Users\Ahmed\AndroidStudioProjects\Shiftind\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.shiftind.www.shiftind
$ adb shell pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.shiftind.www.shiftind"
Success


$ adb shell am start -n "com.shiftind.www.shiftind/com.shiftind.www.shiftind.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 2284 on device emulator-5554
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.shiftind.www.shiftind-2/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.shiftind.www.shiftind, real application class is null.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.shiftind.www.shiftind-2/lib/x86
W/art: Verification of android.support.v4.media.session.MediaControllerCompat android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportMediaController() took 420.734ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.requestPermissionsFromFragment(android.support.v4.app.Fragment, java.lang.String[], int) took 107.527ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.setEnterSharedElementCallback(android.support.v4.app.SharedElementCallback) took 102.953ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onSupportActionModeFinished(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode) took 192.620ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.setHWLayerAnimListenerIfAlpha(android.view.View, android.view.animation.Animation) took 130.794ms
W/art: Verification of android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(android.content.Context, android.view.Window, android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback) took 147.296ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(android.content.Context, android.view.Window, android.support.v7.app.AppCompatCallback) took 138.730ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor() took 166.867ms
W/art: Verification of void android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration) took 215.247ms
W/art: Verification of android.support.v7.view.ActionMode android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.startSupportActionModeFromWindow(android.support.v7.view.ActionMode$Callback) took 113.775ms
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
W/gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed

                  [ 10-02 15:22:33.523  2284: 2284 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa72c2540, tid 2284
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
I/Choreographer: Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                  --------- beginning of crash
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.shiftind.www.shiftind, PID: 2284
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
                   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
                   Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.shiftind.www.shiftind/com.shiftind.www.shiftind.registration}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1805)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1523)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4224)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:48)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4183)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:856)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4507)
                      at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4475)
                      at com.shiftind.www.shiftind.MainActivity.onButtonClick(MainActivity.java:19)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755) 
Application terminated.
```

*my mainActivity.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.shiftind.www.shiftind.MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:text="Let's Get Started"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/startbutton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
        android:onClick="onButtonClick"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="85dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*my registartion.xml (second activity)*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:text="registration activity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="111dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textStyle="normal|bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

*my registration.java*

```
package com.shiftind.www.shiftind;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by Ahmed on 10/2/2016.
 */

public class registration extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.registration);
    }
}
```

*my main activity.java*

```
package com.shiftind.www.shiftind;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onButtonClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.startbutton) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, registration.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the exception... have you declared that activity in the manifest?

Comment: Also, if you aren't, then using File > New Activity is preferred over creating activities by hand until you understand how to do it

Comment: Please include your android manifest, I'm pretty certain something about it is wrong

Comment: I kind of suspect this line `android:onClick="onButtonClick"`; remove it and try setting your onClickListener from within the code (not xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the second Activity in your manifest file and you should be sorted out
Also your button is not declared

Comment: already did that @Vikrant Fernandes but still with the same problem

Comment: @ahmedRezaSiddique see my edit. Also avoid using onClick in XML for buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add this line inside `<application>` tag

```
 <activity android:name=".registration" ></activity>
```

hope it helps